# Get travisCI build environment working for netcdf-dependent Fortran built in R package

Tags: makefile, fortran, travis-ci, r-package

The title should have two subtitles:
*What is the pathname to any installed libraries in the Travis CI environment?*
or
*How do I get my Makevars file portable for NetCDF libraries??*

## Background:

I am developing and R package that is supposed to work with a shared library I have written in Fortran. I want to check my builds with TravisCI, so my package is currently on GitHub.

So upon package installation, the Fortran source code should be compiled. I can do this locally, but TravisCI errors with the following message:

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -c HANDLE_ERR.f90
HANDLE_ERR.f90:4: Error: Can't open included file 'netcdf.inc'
make: *** [HANDLE_ERR.o] Error 1
```

Which I understand as the compiler not finding the NetCDF library, which I made sure I installed by adding this to my `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev -y
```

## Example

I have created a minimal working example, which is failing in TravisCI, with the error message (above) I am getting on my big project. 
See here for the travis build https://travis-ci.org/teatree1212/nctest 
you can access my minimal working example repository from there, but here is the link as well: https://github.com/teatree1212/nctest/tree/master

The compilation works when I do it locally, as I can specify the NetCDF library directories. I don't know where these are installed in the Travis build environment, so I think this is where my problem lies at the moment.

However, I would like to make this package portable and not only make it work in the travis container. Therefore these two questions:

*What is the pathname to any installed libraries in the Travis CI environment?*
and more importantly:
*How do I make my Makevars file portable for compiling with NetCDF libraries?*

Comment: Are you aware (and have available) of the `nf-config` utility?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @francescalus I have not used it. But  I am not sure how I would in this context. I looked at their  `.travis.yml` for comparison, but that doesn't help. I have tried to find any default installation directories I could deduct the one I need from, but without success. That said, I am not that/at all well-versed in config and makefiles.

Comment: But maybe you mean something else? I have looked into [this:](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran)

Comment: ah, so I was hoping to avoid having to write a configure file and work on the assumption that netcdf libraries are installed in default locations.

Comment: `nf-config` (a bit like `pkg-config` but specific to the NetCDF installation), gives the required paths and libraries.  You can read more in the documentation (hopefully), but something like `$(FC) mysource.f90 $(nf-config --flibs ...)` could work.

Comment: @francescalus thanks for this, but I am not knowledgeable enough to apply your advice. 1) should I use this line `$(FC) mysource.f90 $(nf-config --flibs` in my Makevars file? Am I right that you are talking about [this](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran/blob/master/nf-config.in) ? 2) Where do I put this file (`nf-config.in`)? I have added it into the /src folder. See [here](https://travis-ci.org/teatree1212/nctest/builds/411277657) for the failed build, with the same error message, and `Subdirectory ‘src’ contains:
  nf-confic.in
These are unlikely file names for src files.`

Comment: I have not been able to solve this yet. Can anyone help?